# R: Unique count by first occurrence of grouping variable

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to create a new variable "Count" that is a count of the unique values of a factor "Period", by grouping variable "ID". The following data includes a column with the values I would want in "Count":

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), Period = c(1.1, 1.1, 
1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.5), Count = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("ID", "Period", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I tried to use mutate with `Count = 1:length(Period)` but it creates a cumulative count of each value of "Period", whereas I want a cumulative count of only unique values. This is what I tried:

```
library(plyr)
samp1<-ddply(samp, .(ID, Period), mutate, Count = 1:length(Period))
```

Could anyone provide the correct function to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit- New answer**

Now that come to think of it some more, my initial approach won't return correct results if each groups elements aren't grouped together, so for example for

```
v <- c(1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2)
```

My function will put non-consecutive `1`s and `2` in different groups

```
myrleid(v)
## [1] 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

Thus, the best approach seem to be

```
match(v, unique(v))
## [1] 1 2 3 3 1 3
```

Will will both *preserve the appearance order* and *keep un-ordered values in the same group*.

Thus, I would recommend just doing

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Count2 := match(Period, unique(Period)), by = ID]
```

or (with base R)

```
with(df, ave(Period, ID, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
```

---

**Old answer**

Looks like a good candidate for the `rleid` function from the [`data.table` devel](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) version on GH

```
### Devel version installation instructions
# library(devtools)
# install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)

library(data.table) # v 1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, Count2 := rleid(Period), by = ID]
df
#    ID Period Count Count2
# 1:  a    1.1     1      1
# 2:  a    1.1     1      1
# 3:  a    1.2     2      2
# 4:  a    1.3     3      3
# 5:  b    1.2     1      1
# 6:  b    1.3     2      2
# 7:  b    1.5     3      3
# 8:  b    1.5     3      3
```

---

Or, If you don't want to load external packages, we could define this function on our own

```
myrleid <- function(x) {
  temp <- rle(x)$lengths 
  rep.int(seq_along(temp), temp)
}

with(df, ave(Period, ID, FUN = myrleid))
## [1] 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 3
```

---

Or if the groups are in increasing order, you could try ranking them too

```
library(data.table) ## V1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, Count2 := frank(Period, ties.method = "dense"), by = ID]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(Count2 = dense_rank(Period))
```

Comment: Ok, see my edit. I think the new answer is more general for different scenarios.

Comment: So I will have to try your edit. I sorted my dataframe by the the variables that correspond to "ID" and "Period" in my actual dataset first, then ran your original function and that numbered the periods correctly. Thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

```
samp <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), Period = c(1.1, 1.1, 
1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.5), Count = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("ID", "Period", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

select(samp, -Count) %>%
  arrange(ID, Period) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(dup = !duplicated(Period),
         Count = cumsum(dup))
```

The key steps are to arrange by `ID` and `Period`, and then to identify that first new representation of `Period` as "not duplicated".

Answer (score 1):

A solution in base R with `transform`:

```
transform(df, Count2 =  unlist(
                               tapply(df$Period, df$ID, function(x)       
                                       as.numeric(factor(x))) 
                              ))

   ID Period Count Count2
a1  a    1.1     1      1
a2  a    1.1     1      1
a3  a    1.2     2      2
a4  a    1.3     3      3
b1  b    1.2     1      1
b2  b    1.3     2      2
b3  b    1.5     3      3
b4  b    1.5     3      3
```

as David suggested this solution does not work well if data `Period` are not monotonic increasing.